# Find Height of Image

Tags: android, image, android-mapview, drawable

I have a map view with markers on it.  I need do display a popup right above these markers, however, the `MapView.LayoutParams` only accepts pixels as the x-axis offset.  Since the image will be different sizes on different screens, I'm wondering how I can get the height of the `Drawable` in pixels.

Thanks

Comment: are you looking for something like this: http://bit.ly/N2ZmPj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that you need to find the height and width of a particular drawable ?
If that is the case then you can use something like this

```
       BitmapDrawable image_dimen=(BitmapDrawable) this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.imageb);
       int height=image_dimen.getBitmap().getHeight();
       int width=image_dimen.getBitmap().getWidth();
```